# How to find neighbouring polygons with same attribute value?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop

I have certain amount of polygons with different classes (numbers). I would like select/find all these polygons that have a neighbor-polygon with the same class.

Is there a tool in  QGIS, ArcGIS (basic)? What would be the right approach?

Here an example of the data set:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In ArcGIS, you could run a dissolve, using the value field as the dissolve field. Then use the features to points tool to create points for each of your original polygons. then use a spatial join of the dissolved shapes to the point layer, which will give you a count of the number of points (and therefore, polygons) within each dissolved polygons. any shape with a count of higher than 1 means that it was formed from that many adjacent polygons.
you could then select by location from your original polygons to only select those that are within one of the dissolved polygons made from 2 or more shapes

Comment: This looks like it should work.  An alternative approach could be to use Polygon Neighbors and arcpy.da but it may or may not be slower.

Comment: Thanks, for your comments.
Finally, I used the Polygon Neighbor (ArcGIS) function. I related the output table (from the polygon neighbor tool) with my initial polygon layer. Next I did a selection (via select by attributes) on the output table from the polygon neighbor tool (source class = neighbor class). With the switch to related table "bottom" I got then also the selection for the initial polygon layer....